# How do I rearrange my array values so relations to columns stay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Before I ask a question I have to describe my program a bit (Please tell if something is unclear).

The code goes through X nr of sorting-elements based on how many columns are fetched from a file and then html is generated is based on that.

*5 columns would generate something like this (without the actual formatting in tables etc where the inputs resides but I don't think it's important for this question):* (It *could* be 55 columns as well)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sorting[1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="sorting[2]">
<input type="checkbox" name="sorting[3]">
<input type="checkbox" name="sorting[4]">
<input type="checkbox" name="sorting[5]">

<select name="sortiteration_col[1]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="0">Iteration1</option>
<option value="1">Iteration2</option>
<option value="2">Iteration3</option>
<option value="3">Iteration4</option>
<option value="4">Iteration5</option>
</select>

<select name="sortiteration_col[2]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="0">Iteration1</option>
<option value="1">Iteration2</option>
<option value="2">Iteration3</option>
<option value="3">Iteration4</option>
<option value="4">Iteration5</option>
</select>

<select name="sortiteration_col[3]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="0">Iteration1</option>
<option value="1">Iteration2</option>
<option value="2">Iteration3</option>
<option value="3">Iteration4</option>
<option value="4">Iteration5</option>
</select>

<select name="sortiteration_col[4]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="0">Iteration1</option>
<option value="1">Iteration2</option>
<option value="2">Iteration3</option>
<option value="3">Iteration4</option>
<option value="4">Iteration5</option>
</select>

<select name="sortiteration_col[5]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="0">Iteration1</option>
<option value="1">Iteration2</option>
<option value="2" selected="">Iteration3</option>
<option value="3">Iteration4</option>
<option value="4">Iteration5</option>
</select>
```

The `sortiteration_col` defines in which order sorting colums are generated:
(iteration 0-4 is relative to column 1-5)

`1,2,3,4,5` is "normal order". Then column 1 is set to iteration 0, column 2 is set to iteration 1, column 3 is set to iteration 2, column 4 is set to iteration 3 and column 5 is set to iteration 4.

Maybe user want to set `4,5,2,3,1` and then column 4 is set to iteration 0, 5 is set to iteration 1, 2 is set to iteration 2, 3 is set to iteration 3 and 1 is set to iteration 4.

*The user defines this for each column where he/she sets iteration number* (from sortiteration_col[column_nr].

**In jQuery I have this code:**

```
$('div input[name^="sorting"]').each(function( index ) {
  var this_name = $(this).attr('name'),
  col_number  = this_name.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];

        
  //Get iteration value (which order should the sorting be done)
  //for this column
  var iteration = $('div select[name="sortiteration_col[' + col_number + ']"');

  var iteration_nr = null;
  if (iteration.length>0) {
    iteration_nr = iteration.val();
  }

  console.log('COL ' + col_number + ': Iteration nr=' + iteration_nr);

});
```

From **console.log** I get this:

```
COL 1: Iteration nr=2
COL 2: Iteration nr=0
COL 3: Iteration nr=1
COL 4: Iteration nr=3
COL 5: Iteration nr=4
```

I want the user to be able to sort in a custom order.. Instead of just 1,2,3,4,5  in the case below: 2,3,1,4,5

```
I want to do this below but not with hardcoded values ofc:

colorder_arr.push(2); //Add COL nr (iteration 0 = col 2 from above)
colorder_arr.push(3); //Add COL nr (iteration 1 = col 3 from above)
colorder_arr.push(1); //Add COL nr (iteration 2 = col 1 from above)
colorder_arr.push(4); //Add COL nr (iteration 3 = col 4 from above)
colorder_arr.push(5); //Add COL nr (iteration 4 = col 5 from above)
```

**How do I get correct column values to add in the colorder_arr** ?

---

**EDITED/UPDATED** for clarification:

**Skip everything about forms for a while** :-)

**I have this array**

```
  var iterationorder_col = [2,0,1,3,4];
```

Lets say this array relates to columns 1,2,3,4,5 (number of items in `iterationsorder_col`).

**This would mean**

- 2 relates to column 3
- 0 relates to column 1
- 1 relates to column 2
- 3 relates to column 4
- 4 relates to column 5.

*(value from item + 1 = column nr)*
This would produce an array: `[3,1,2,4,5]`

**But I want these to be rearranged like this:**

- value 2 (because it's value 0 in `iterationorder_col` )
- value 3 (because it's value 1 in `iterationorder_col` )
- value 1 (because it's value 2 in `iterationorder_col` )
- value 4 (because it's value 3 in `iterationorder_col` )
- value 5 (because it's value 4 in `iterationorder_col` )

*(Note 0,1,2,3,4)*

Therefore the new array should contain:

```
[2,3,1,4,5]
```

I'm thinking *something* like this:

```
var new_cols = [];

for(i=0;i<iterationorder_col.length;i++) {          
    for (j=0;j<iterationorder_col.length;j++) {
        if ( iterationorder_col[i] == j) {
            new_cols.push(j);
            break;
        }      
     }

}
```

but this code obviously does not work :-)

Comment: From where will the "colorder_arr" get data?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios - based on var iteration = $('div select[name="sortiteration_col[' + col_number + ']"'); and actual colnr: col_number. It's a new array I want to add based on the how columns and iterations relate to eachother.

Comment: I think i can help you, but last question, why are you using checkbox with a name "sorting[n]"?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios - actually it's a radiobutton (I saw I typed wrong in question) but to explain why it would require a whole new question. I don't believe it's important for my question. The reason I included was just to clearify that it was a formelement array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now It´s more clear what you need! Let´s start with your array:

```
var iterationorder_col = [2,0,1,3,4];
```

Now, you need to get the index of each element in the array, It means that:

- Value 0 has index 1
- Value 1 has index 2
- Value 2 has index 0
- Value 3 has index 3
- Value 4 has index 4

For doing this, I recommend to use the `indexOf()` function which returns the index of an element inside an array. You can do it with a `for()` instruction:

```
var index_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < iterationorder_col.length; i++) {
    index_array[i] = iterationorder_col.indexOf(i);
}
```

This would give as a result an array `index_array = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4]`
Notice that the array you want to obtain at the end is equal to the **index_array + 1 (each item + 1)**.
So `final_array = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]`, to achieve this, you can make an addition into each item of the index array, or you can just modified the last `for()` instruction like this:

```
var final_array= [];

for (var i = 0; i < iterationorder_col.length; i++) {
    final_array[i] = iterationorder_col.indexOf(i) + 1;  //notice the +1 increment
}
```

That´s all ;-)
You can try the complete code in this snippet

```js
var iterationorder_col = [2,0,1,3,4];

var final_array= [];

for (var i = 0; i < iterationorder_col.length; i++) {
    final_array[i] = iterationorder_col.indexOf(i) + 1;  //notice the +1 increment
}

console.log(final_array);
```

Comment: The only thing that is important is var iteration = $('div select[name="sortiteration_col[' + col_number + ']"'); AND which columnnr it is. That should be enough to answer what I want. I loop through the elemens sorting $('div input[name^="sorting"]') but I could as well loop through $('div input[name^="sortiteration_col"]') (It's the same number of iterations so it would not matter).

Comment: I have just edited it. Look if that is what you want

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. I will have to clarify my question :-)

Comment: I edited my post. Maybe I have the solution now :-)

Comment: I've updated it again and skipped everything about the form-stuff. Just a simple array and what I want to do with that array. I hope it got clearar what I wanted. It's clearer for me now :-)

Comment: Now I understand what you need, look again my answer!

Comment: aha thank you very much sir! It was indexof I was "looking for" :-)